# What regulations govern the quality management system for producers of aircraft components?

Tags: faa-regulations

I am looking for FAA documents and regulations regarding the quality management system for producers of aircraft components.
Specifically I would like to know what is a **production certificate** .

Furthermore may I download those regulation somewhere ?

Answer (score 4):

From FAA, [Production Certificate](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/production_approvals/prod_cert/):

> A production certificate is an approval (document) to manufacture
>   duplicate products under an FAA-approved type design (e.g., type
>   certificate or supplemental type certificate). The holder of a
>   production certificate may obtain an airworthiness certificate for
>   aircraft produced under the production certificate without further
>   showing. To obtain one, the production application and approval
>   process must be followed.

See also: 
Production Approval - Regulations & Policies ([link](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/production_approvals/prod_cert/pc_regs/)).

Comment: Are there any link to PDF download of these regulation ? 
And please explain me that thing: I am company A (e.g. Boeing) who project and built the airplane, but I need a lot of components, so I have company B producing those components. Company B needs to have a production certificate right ? This certificate refers to one specific product or covers every product of certain categories for example ?
Hope being clear...!

Comment: Detail in [subpart G](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=da23626c21aa97af26bbc2622a9f78d8&mc=true&node=pt14.1.21&rgn=div5#sp14.1.21.g). Also look at documents that are mentionned, e.g. [Docket No. FAA-2006-25877](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/production_approvals/14cfr_amendments/media/FAA-2006-25877.pdf). I guess the certificate may encompass multiple products, but this is likely explained in the process you need to follow for the request, as company B. I usually get pdf for 14 CFR at [cornell.edu](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14)

Answer (score 2):

It's all covered under [14 CFR Part 21](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=052d2ec8f9deede10fd2cd612b15fa08&mc=true&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr21_main_02.tpl).

**Production Certificates** provide authorization for production to holders of a Type Certificate - typically the aircraft or engine manufacturer. Suppliers to the Production Certificate holder can produce components under one of two types of authorization.

If the part being manufactured is defined by the the OEM's Type Certificate (an OEM part numbered drawing), they can produce it under a PMA - Parts Manufacturing Approval. (14 CFR Part 21, Subpart K).

If the part is covered by a TSO - Technical Standard Order, the supplier can produce the part under a TSOA - TSO Authorization.  (14 CFR Part 21, Subpart O).